# eslint-plugin-jsdoc does not get executed

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've followed the instructions in the docs - installed the plugin locally, added it to `plugins` in `.eslintrc`, added the rules, now when I run `npm run lint` - my previous linting rules get checked, but not the new ones.

Comment: Your question is not reproducible.

Comment: @golopot I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - should have updated my eslint version and pay more attention to `npm install` output which states exactly this.